# jQuery validate remote parsing two fields in one call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, validation

Currently I'm trying to parse two values though jQuerys validate plugin to check against an SQL database. I can see that DateReceived is being parsed correctly, but CentreID is always coming up as null.

Here's my current code:

```
var centreID = $( '#CentreSelect' ).val();
    $("#submit-form").validate({
        rules: {
            DateReceived:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "url.php?CentreID=" + centreID,
                    type: "GET"
                    }
                },
            },
        messages: {
            DateReceived: {
                    remote: "Error - Centre already entered on that date"
                    }
            }
    });
});
```

An suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
$("#submit-form").validate({
    rules: {
        DateReceived: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "url.php?CentreID=" + centreID,
                data: {
                    CentreID: function () {
                        //you need to read this value when the validation is executed, so pass the value as a function which will be called
                        return $('#CentreSelect').val()
                    }
                }
                type: "GET"
            }
        },
    },
    messages: {
        DateReceived: {
            remote: "Error - Centre already entered on that date"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man try to read the centreID after you call the validate function.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" if I try to read the value into a variable. If I try to read the value straight into the URL string, I get the same error.